# Creating simple http request in node-red

Tags: raspbian, nodered

I'm new to the Raspberry Pi.

I just started using node red to create a flow but I got stuck in making a simple http request. This is the [flow](http://blog.karthicksp.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/nodered11.png) I created, but whenever I make a request to go to the http interface I get cannot get `/ipl/tweets`. Should I configure anything?

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5o4tIz2Zzc).

Comment: Your link is dead already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated node red using the following tutorial and deleted the http request node and added it again this seems to get resolved

http://nodered.org/docs/hardware/raspberrypi#upgrading

Comment: As this worked for you could you please mark it as correct.